# Datepicker not displays when input hide according to selected category

Tags: jquery, html, vue.js, datepicker

I'm currently working on a project in `Laravel` & `VueJs`. I have the following dropdown list.

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="form.type" @change="typeChange()">
    <option value="1">Repair</option>
    <option value="2">PM</option>
    <option value="3">Upgrade/NFC</option>
</select>
```

According to the selected option, some fields appear like if I select **PM** following input field appears

```
<input name="latest_pm_date" v-model="form.latest_pm_date" class="form-control boost-date" id="latest_pm_date" required="" placeholder="">
```

But the Datepicker is not appearing when I click on the above input field. I use following code when the page loads:

```
mounted(){
    jQuery(".boost-date").datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD ',
    }).on('dp.change',  function(e) {
        let event = new Event('input');
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
}
```

However, I also used the above datepicker also in `typeChange()` function.

```
typeChange(){
    this.form.reminder_id = "";

    jQuery(".boost-date").datetimepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD ',
    }).on('dp.change',  function(e) {
        let event = new Event('input');
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    });
}
```

Still, datepicker is not appearing. I think the reason for this is this input field is hidden when the page loads. And after I select **PM** from dropdown only this input field appears.

Can someone point me out what's the mistake here? Your help will be very much appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

If it is "hidden" by `v-if` it is not in the DOM, so jQuery can't find it via `jQuery(".boost-date")`

You can try to solve it by using `v-show` which hid via CSS but the elements are not added or removed from the DOM.